# Chrome Selenium Crashing with Docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been looking everywhere for an answer with no luck. I've got a Python script that works fine locally running Selenium with a Chrome Driver, which I'm now testing in Docker.

The script is running fine until the webdriver kicks in, at which point I get the error message *"unknown error: session deleted because of page crash"*.

I've seen some suggestions that extending the memory allowance could fix this but I've had no luck. To be honest my knowldege of the docker-compose file is quite poor so any suggestions on what I could change with this file would be helpful too (see below).

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  lambda:
    build: .
    environment:
      - PYTHONPATH=/var/task/src:/var/task/lib
      - PATH=/var/task/bin
      - AWS_BUCKET_NAME=REMOVED
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=REMOVED
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=REMOVED
      - AWS_REGION=ap-southeast-2
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/task/src/
```